# Click handler variables only global

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that in click handlers you cannot have variables passed to the function. So you are forced to always declare them globally. Am I right about this ?

For example:

```
$("#modalCancel,#modalClose").click(function()
{
   if(update == false)
   {
        modalCloseCancel(testcaseId);
   }
   else
   {
        modalCloseCancelUpdate(testcaseId, $("#radio-previous_"+testcaseId).val());
   }
});
```

Here update and testcaseId are variables which change . I cannot pass them as parameter to function() , but instead I need to declare them globally above the handler. I think there is no other way.So in case there are other functions below they must be careful.

Comment: Could you add more information about the context around your function? Where des `testcaseId` comes from?

Comment: it's just a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily store variables on the element themselves, using `data-*` attributes and `.data` method:

```js
$('.clickme').on('click',function(){
   var update = $(this).data("update");
   console.log(update);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickme" data-update="true">Click me (true)</button>
<button class="clickme" data-update="false">Click me (false)</button>
```

Comment: aha. Ok. At least one way.